# How to Update Entity Model properly after change of data base Structure

Tags: asp.net, entity, modal-dialog

**i am Already use entity modal in my project.**
i want update my entity modal from database because i change in database structure****(ADD THREE TABLE ).****
but when i update my entity modal this update.
but when i run project it will be give invalid object name "table name".
i am not delete my entity modal because my project will be big.
this project on Asp.net with VS 2010.
please give me well solution because i am first time update entity modal
this 
 i am only update three tables in Entity modal from database but error in other tables.

**please tall me that how can update entity modal properly**

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried migrating it? Below is a link how to use code first migrations

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621.aspx

Comment: i can't understand that what are you staying to me Please explain because i am new for entity modal

Comment: Your questions is a little hard to understand.  From what i get it sounds like you been using Entity Framework. You made a site and now you need to change the Database Schema/ Add to? Am i correct so far?